# Adding column to dataframe based on values in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, pivot-table

I have two dataframes the first one:

**df1**:

```
   product     price
0  apples      1.99
1  bananas     1.20 
2  oranges     1.49
3  lemons      0.5
4  Olive Oil   8.99
```

**df2:**

```
   product     product.1     product.2 
0  apples      bananas       Olive Oil
1  bananas     lemons        oranges
2  Olive Oil   bananas       oranges
3  lemons      apples        bananas
```

I want a column in the second dataframe to be the sum of the prices base on the price of each item in the first dataframe. So desired outcome would be:

```
   product     product.1     product.2     total_price 
0  apples      bananas       Olive Oil     12.18
1  bananas     lemons        oranges       3.19
2  Olive Oil   bananas       oranges       11.68
3  lemons      apples        bananas       3.69
```

What is the best way to accomplish this? I have tried merging the dataframes on the name for each of the columns in df2 but this seems time consuming especially as df1 gets more rows and df2 gets more columns.

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='right', left_on='product', right_on='product')
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='right', left_on='product', right_on='product.1')
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='right', left_on='product', right_on='product.2') 
df['Total_Price'] = df['price']+df['price.1']+df['price.2']
```

Comment: Is it ok to change df1 to dictionary and map values or is df1 to large to change to dict?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like below:

1. First, converting df1 to dictionary of keys and values
2. Using dictionary in above with `applymap` followed by `sum`

May be following snippet will do something similar:

```
dictionary_val = { k[0]: k[1] for k in df1.values }
df2['Total_Price'] = df2.applymap(lambda row: dictionary_val[row]).sum(axis=1) # Note not creating new dataframe but using existing one
```

Then result is `df2`:

```
    product    product.1    product.2   Total_Price
0   apples      bananas     Olive Oil    12.18
1   bananas     lemons      oranges      3.19
2   Olive Oil   bananas     oranges      11.68
3   lemons      apples      bananas      3.69
```